# Dealing with Quotes in Query Result PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to pull a series of strings from a mysql database to be used in a php page.

I use this function:

```
function getText(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
    $texts = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM texts;');
    return $texts;
 }
```

I then do this:  `array = $tests->fetch_assoc()` to get a row of the associative array. I then access the text with `$array["text"]` The problem I am having is that the text that I am retrieving needs to have `"` in them because of the use case but the `$array["text"]` only includes the text before the first `"`. What is the best way to remedy this?

Comment: Have you checked the complete value is in the database or could the problem be with the INSERT?

Comment: @Eelke Already checked, yep it is in the database correctly

Comment: PHP and mysqli are not going to chop a string in half because it happened to contain a `"`.

Comment: @MarcB Any ideas why I am getting this behavior then?

Comment: what's in this text? If it contains html/xml tags, then do a `view source` in your browser. they're probably there but just not being displayed because the browser is parsing/rendering the tags

Comment: Have your tried `$array['text']`. Well even `$array[text]` should work although it's discouraged.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot I think Marc B has the right idea, it is probably not the $array["text"] that has problem, but instead of the way you use that string. i.e. the string corrupts your html and cause the second half to be hidden.

Comment: @JackyCheng yep that was it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sql returns something that is cut off then there are two (simple) answers

1. This is what was in the database
2. encoding problems.

The *2nd* is not an issue here.
The **1st** items could be a case.

- You have too short field for text.
- Your insert is erasing the data after 1st " because its not escaped

If you may `var_dump($texts);` in your function you will see if data from database have errors already or its somewhere deeper in your code.

If its deeper then i would suggest you to add `addslashes` or entity encode for the ,,corruept'' strings - that can prevent your code from messing with it later.

Comment: Thanks... problem was the inclusion in the html